# Get MP3 ID3 (V2) tags using id3v2

Tags: bash, shell, id3lib

I'm having a little difficulty understanding the format of V2 ID3 tags. I simply want to get the 'Genre' ID3 tag of an MP3 file, but the id3v2 utility returns more information than I require, and I don't understand what this data represents.

For example, I'm using the following bash code:

```
id3v2 -l "$FILE" | grep -i "content type"
```

Which returns something on the lines of:

`TCON (Content type): Jazz (8)`

Really I just want to know if it's safe for me to assume this will always be the format, and thus is it safe for me to do the following?:

```
id3v2 -l "$FILE" | grep -i "content type" | sed "s/^.*: //" | sed "s/ (.*$//"
```

(Which would result in "Jazz".)

I'm trying to find the best way to get the ID3 'Genre' tag. Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is safe to assume that the line will be prefixed with TCON, so I would rather search for that (this will be i18n safe as well).

```
id3v2 -l "$FILE" | sed -n '/^TCON/s/^.*: //p' | sed 's/ (.*//'
```

(no need to run grep)

---

From /usr/share/doc/id3lib-3.8.3/doc/id3v2.3.0.txt

> TCON
>
> The 'Content type', which
>   previously was stored as a one byte
>   numeric    value only, is now a
>   numeric string. You may use one or
>   several of    the types as ID3v1.1 did
>   or, since the category list would be
>   impossible to maintain with accurate
>   and up to date categories,    define
>   your own.
>
> References to the ID3v1 genres can
>   be made by, as first byte, enter "(" followed by a number from the
>   genres list (appendix A.) and ended
>   with a ")" character. This is
>   optionally followed by a 
>   refinement, e.g. "(21)" or
>   "(4)Eurodisco". Several references can
>   be    made in the same frame, e.g.
>   "(51)(39)". If the refinement should 
>   begin with a "(" character it should
>   be replaced with "((", e.g. "((I 
>   can figure out any genre)" or "(55)((I
>   think...)". The following new 
>   content types is defined in ID3v2 and
>   is implemented in the same way    as
>   the numerig content types, e.g.
>   "(RX)".
>
> ```
>  RX  Remix
>  CR  Cover
> ```